# Getting "object variable or with block variable not set" within Outlook VBA sometimes

Tags: vba, outlook

I have a fairly straightforward VBA script that accepts meeting requests in Outlook (2013). It works fine most of the times, but for some meeting requests it gives me "object variable or with block variable not set" on this line
        Set oResponse = oAppt.Respond(olMeetingAccepted, True)

I've tried to look at the different meeting requests to figure out any differences which might be triggering it but for all purposes they look like identical requests (of course they're from different senders with different subject and time, but nothing that I can see as triggering a fail).

Any thoughts what might be going on? Here's the complete Sub (it gets triggered by an outlook rule)

```
Sub AutoAcceptMeetings(oRequest As MeetingItem)

Dim senderName As String
Dim subjectName As String
Dim meetingTime As String
Dim senderContains As Integer
Dim subjectContains As Integer
Dim oResponse As MeetingItem
Dim oAppt As AppointmentItem
On Error GoTo debugs

If oRequest.MessageClass <> "IPM.Schedule.Meeting.Request" Then
    Exit Sub
End If

Set oAppt = oRequest.GetAssociatedAppointment(True)

senderName = oRequest.senderName
subjectName = oRequest.Subject


senderContains = InStr(1, senderName, "Gina")
'Her meeting invitations don't have a reminder set.
If (senderContains > 0) Then
    oAppt.ReminderSet = True
    oAppt.ReminderMinutesBeforeStart = 15
End If

senderContains = InStr(1, senderName, "Jim")

If (senderContains > 0)  Then 'I don't want a reminder
    oAppt.ReminderSet = False
    oAppt.BusyStatus = olTentative
    oAppt.Save
    Else 'useful meetings. accept and send response.
    meetingTime = oAppt.Start
    Set oResponse = oAppt.Respond(olMeetingAccepted, True)
    oResponse.Send
    MsgBox ("Meeting accepted " + subjectName + " from " + senderName + " for " + meetingTime)
End If

debugs:
If Err.Description <> "" Then MsgBox (Err.Description + " - Source: AutoAcceptMeetings")
End Sub
```

Comment: That error means oAppt is nothing, which seems to mean that oRequest has no AssociatedAppointment. Not sure what that means, but that's how I read the error.

Comment: Thanks Doug, that would've made sense. However, I am able to get the meetingTime correctly from oAppt (and it prints out correctly when I tested).

Comment: Of course. And you can accept an appointment that has the error? (In the front end).

Comment: Thank you Doug, I think that probably explains it. I am able to accept it fine from the front end, but it's one of those meetings where the sender is not expecting a response. So, I just need to figure out a test to see if it's one of those. Any thoughts?

Comment: This seems to do the trick. Thanks again Doug !

If (oAppt.ResponseRequested) Then

Comment: You are welcome. Interesting question.

Comment: I rolled back your edit. If you want to share a solution to the problem, do so in the space below titled *Your Answer*. We don't put *solved* in the title here.

Answer (score 0):

So, the issue was that I was trying to send a "response" to a meeting request that didn't require any responses. On the front end (outlook) if you accept the meeting, it goes into your calendar and the request gets deleted but no response goes to the organizer (people do that when they invite a large group and don't necessarily care to know who's attending).

Anyway, the solution for me was to put in a simple check before actually responding to the request.

```
If (oAppt.ResponseRequested) Then
    Set oResponse = oAppt.Respond(olMeetingAccepted, True)
    oResponse.Send
End If
```